# Vanilla JavaScript search - how to show results only when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this function to fetch a JSON with data to be searched. Now, as soon as someone type the keywords a list of relative data is immediately shown. I'd like to show the results only when button is clicked. But I cannot find a way.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  const search = document.getElementById('search');
  const results = document.getElementById('results');
  let data = [];
  let search_term = '';

  fetch('/search.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data_server => {
      data = data_server;
    });

  search.addEventListener('input', event => {
    search_term = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    showList();
  });

  const showList = () => {
    results.innerHTML = '';
    if (search_term.length <= 0) return;
    const match = new RegExp(`${search_term}`, 'gi');
    let result = data.filter(name => match.test(name.title) || match.test(name.meta_description) || match.test(name.tags));
    if (result.length == 0) {
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = `No results found`;
      results.appendChild(li);
    }
    result.forEach(e => {
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = `<a href="${e.url}">${e.title}</a><br>${e.meta_description}`;
      results.appendChild(li);
    });
  };
});
```

And this is the search input:

```
            <input autocomplete="off" type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
            <ul id="results"></ul>
```

Comment: `const btn = document.getElementById('theButton');`  and then `btn.addEventListener('click', event => { search_term = search.value.toLowerCase(); /* rest of the code */`

Comment: yes, so you need to search only on the button event, but don't forget to remove `search.addEventListener('input', event => {
    search_term = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    showList();
  });` to avoid searching on input changes

Comment: @GrafiCode and @tromgy, tried both your suggestions but it does not work: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  const btn = document.getElementById('theButton');
  btn.addEventListener('click', event => { search_term = search.value.toLowerCase();`  /*rest of the code*/ and removed the part as tromgy suggests

Comment: You also need to set the id on your Button 
<button type="submit" id="theButton">Search</button>

Comment: Yes, I did set the button ID. Now I've found the problem: it was missing     `showList();
  });`, re-added and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @rocco you can self-answer your question (and even self-accept it), please post the working code for future reference https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer